# Doubt about file access rights between user/groups

Tags: permissions

I am the single user on this Linux machine. I tried the following procedure to protect files, but it does not work as I expected. Could someone explain why?

```
$ touch file
$ sudo chown root:root file
$ sudo chmod a-w file
$ ls -l file
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 0 2012-02-29 01:06 file
$ rm file
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `file'? yes
$ ls -l file
ls: cannot access file: No such file or directory
```

"File" is read-only and owned by root. Why was my regular user able to delete it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is an odd behavior of linux permissions, but permissions to delete files are granted by the permissions on the directory, not the file.

Try this:

```
mkdir test
touch test/file

# Make the Directory ro
chmod a-w test

ls -l test/file
-rw-rw-r-- 1 bodhi bodhi 0 2012-02-28 21:13 test/file

rm test/file
rm: cannot remove `test/file': Permission denied
```

> Write permission. On a regular file, this means you can modify the file, aka write new data to the file. **In the case of a directory, the write permission means you can add, remove, and rename files in the directory.** This means that if a file has the write permission bit, you are allowed to modify the file's contents, **but you're allowed to rename or delete the file only if the permissions of the file's directory allow you to do so**.

See http://www.tuxfiles.org/linuxhelp/filepermissions.html

To allow (RW) access to file, but prevent deletion or renaming, set the sticky bit on the directory.

```
# change "test" to your directory
chmod +t test
touch test/file
chmod a+w test/file

ls -l | grep test
drwxrwxrwt 4 bodhi bodhi  4096 2012-03-07 17:08 test

ls -l test | grep file
-rw-rw-rw- 1 bodhi bodhi   13 2012-03-07 17:10 file

# su to another user, "test"
test@ufbt:/home/bodhi$ echo 'It works !!!' >> test/file

test@ufbt:/home/bodhi$ cat test/file
It works !!!

test@ufbt:/home/bodhi$ rm test/file
rm: cannot remove `test/file': Operation not permitted
```

http://www.techcuriosity.com/resources/linux/advanced_file_permissions_in_linux.php

> If the sticky bit is set for a directory, only the owner of that directory or the owner of a file can delete or rename a file within that directory.

Comment: So, if you want to prevent the folder's content to be deleted or modified, but still being accessible, how should my permissions look like for the directory and its contents?

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: "It is an odd behavior of linux permissions" Odd or correct? ;) @Pomario if you want better control use ACL.